# Is there way to read a text file from an assembly by using Reflection in C#?

Tags: assemblies

I have a text file inside the assembly say MyAssembly. I am trying to access that text file from the code like this :

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).GetFile("data");
```

where data is data.txt file containing some data and I have added that .txt as Embedded Resources.  I have dome reading of the images from the Assebly as embedded resources with code like this :

```
protected Stream GetLogoImageStream()
       {

           Assembly current = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           string imageFileNameFormat = "{0}.{1}";
          string imageName = "myLogo.GIF";

           string assemblyName = current.ManifestModule.Name;
           int extensionIndex = assemblyName.LastIndexOf(".dll", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
           string file = string.Format(imageFileNameFormat, assemblyName.Remove(extensionIndex, 4), imageName);            
           Stream thisImageStream = current.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
           return thisImageStream;

       }
```

However, this approach did not work while reading the .txt file from an the executing assembly. I would really appreciate if anybody can point me to the approach to read .txt file from an assembly. Please dont ask me why I am not reading the file from the drive or the network share. Just say that the requirement is to read the .txt file from the Assembly.

Thank you so  much

Comment: This should work exactly the same for text files as it does for images - what do you mean that this approach did not work? Do you get an Exception?

Comment: Well, I did not get any exception , but the method returned NULL.

Answer (score 3):

`GetManifestResourceStream` is indeed the correct way to read the data. However, when it returns `null`, that usually means you have specified the wrong name. Specifying the correct name is not as simple as it seems. The rules are:

- The VB.NET compiler generates a resource name of `<root namespace>.<physical filename>`.
- The C# compiler generates a resource name of `<default namespace>.<folder location>.<physical filename>`, where `<folder location>` is the relative folder path of the file within the project, using dots as path separators.

You can call the `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames` method in the debugger to check the actual names generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work. GetManifestResourceStream returns null, if the resource is not found. Try checking the run-time value of your *file* variable with the actual name of the resource stored in the assembly (you could check it using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)).

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate for everybody's help on this question. I was able to read the file with the code like this :

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] nameList = a.GetManifestResourceNames();
            string manifestanme = string.Empty;
            if (nameList != null && nameList.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string name in nameList)
                {
                    if (name.IndexOf("c.txt") != -1)
                    {
                        manifestanme = name;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Stream stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(manifestanme);
```

Thanks and +1 for Christian Hayter for this method : a.GetManifestResourceNames();